# How to a create grid view with a fixed number of columns in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to create a calendar component for my app. Currently I'm working on a calendar view that is meant to show 7 days wide month, where each day is a list of events.

To do so I need to inform `GridView` that I always want it to be formatted in a way to hold 7 elements in each row without gaps between them. The underlying collection would always contain multiple of seven elements.

What I currently have (`ExtendedGridView`/`ExtendedListView` are the same basic `GridView`/`ListView` and do not do any visual transformations):

```
<local:ExtendedGridView  x:Name="gridView" Margin="0"
                             IsSwipeEnabled="True"                                     
                             IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                             SelectionMode="Single"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding GroupCollection}"
                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

        <local:ExtendedGridView.DataContext>
            <local:MainViewModel/>
        </local:ExtendedGridView.DataContext>
        <local:ExtendedGridView.Resources>                
            <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultGridItemTemplate">
                <Grid Width="100*" Height="60*" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <local:ExtendedListView Margin="0"
                                            IsSwipeEnabled="False"
                                            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Group}">
                        <local:ExtendedListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style
                                TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Setter
                                    Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                                    Value="Stretch" />
                                <Setter
                                    Property="VerticalAlignment"
                                    Value="Stretch" />
                            </Style>
                        </local:ExtendedListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                        <local:ExtendedListView.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultInnerListItemTemplate">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}" 
                                               FontSize="12" Foreground="Green"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </local:ExtendedListView.Resources>
                        <local:ExtendedListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <Binding Source="{StaticResource DefaultInnerListItemTemplate}"/>
                        </local:ExtendedListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </local:ExtendedListView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

            <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="DefaultGridPanelTemplate">
                <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="7" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Stretch" VerticalChildrenAlignment="Stretch">
                </WrapGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </local:ExtendedGridView.Resources>
        <local:ExtendedGridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style
                TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Setter
                    Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                    Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter
                    Property="VerticalAlignment"
                    Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </local:ExtendedGridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <local:ExtendedGridView.ItemTemplate>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource DefaultGridItemTemplate}"/>
        </local:ExtendedGridView.ItemTemplate>
        <local:ExtendedGridView.ItemsPanel>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource DefaultGridPanelTemplate}"/>
        </local:ExtendedGridView.ItemsPanel>
    </local:ExtendedGridView>
```

How it currently looks:

[image: Screenshot of GridView]

I'm fairly new to  using XAML so maybe I should take a completely different route. Any help and advices are appreciated.

Comment: Did you try decreasing the height of the Grid in the DefaultGridItemTemplate?

Comment: @KenTucker sure, and the same goes for width. There are 7 columns on the screenshot only because of the hardcoded width property. The gaps do not react to it though.

Comment: take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240134/reduce-the-bottom-and-top-space-in-listview-in-xamluwp-universal-windows-platfo

Comment: @KenTucker thank you for the link. Negative value for margin does the trick and I'll use it if nothing else helps. I'm not sure it would work with any layout though. Back in WPF there was `CellSpacing` but it's not present in UWP =(

Comment: You need a `UniformGrid`. There's no built-in one available but you should be able to find one easily on Google.

Comment: @JustinXL thanks, I've mostly managed to implement the same logic manually

Answer (score 2):

It would be great if you can create multiple visual state for different screen where you need to display this gridview and fix columns width accordingly. you can follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate)

Comment: I can not. My software would be used on both tablets and PCs. Maybe I misunderstood you but do you propose manually creating configuration for each of nearly infinite quantity of displays? If yes, then unfortunately it's not an option.

Comment: Thanks for the idea though ^-^